# What are the "proper" names for Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, site-name

Just curious. What are the "official" names for Stack Exchange sites?

I ask because I notice a discrepancy for certain sites. For instance https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ is called *Programming Puzzles & Code Golf* in [many](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) [places](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta&page=1), but *Code Golf* in [others](https://stackexchange.com/sites#), so I don't know what the "real" name is.

If, as I fear, those designations are supposed to be the same, and there is a mismatch somewhere, does that mean the names are stored in more than one place in the database? That would be a horrible thought! Or am I simply missing something?

Comment: Also, `Ask Ubuntu` vs `Ubuntu-Stack Exchange`? Which is correct?

Comment: I guess the official name is what you see on the left-side of top (main) header on the homepage of a particular Stack Exchange site.

Comment: "official" names for Trilogy sites are listed in [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40353/165773)

Comment: Is it possible that, instead of storing it in different places in a database, in the database there's an official and abbreviated name for every SE? That example for "Code Golf" is an incredibly small space initially.

Comment: @Xaade If you mean a shorter name was chosen on [that page](http://stackexchange.com/sites#) because of screen space restraints, in that case it wasn't done very consistently. For instance, the name "Software Quality Assurance and Testing" doesn't even fit; they could have chosen a shorter one there as well.

Comment: @MrLister No, I'm not suggesting a shorter name was chosen *because of screen restraints.* I'm suggesting they have the option to create a shorthand name, and it's used whenever needed. There's no opportunity for people choosing the short name to see everywhere it's used. See Jaydles answer. It appears I guessed close, but the reverse is true. The shorthand is the url, and a detailed name is optional.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it depends a little what you mean by "proper".   That said:

- **Every site* has a "short name"  that is in its url**, preceding ".stackechange.com", ("gaming", "money", "diy"etc.) and which is used in most of the "official" records
- **Some sites also have a longer or more boutique name that is used in the site's header** ("Arqade", "Personal Finance and Money", "Home Improvement", etc.)

EDIT: Having read the comments, I'm not sure there's a definitive answer here.

Internally, people will say both "Gaming" and "Arqade".  Similarly, I tend to call the Home Improvement site "DIY", but others call it "Home Improvement", which is probably closer to its "proper" name.  I think some of the confusion stems from the fact that some sites have boutique names, while others don't.

Comment: No, I don't mean URLs; I specifically mean the discrepancy between, e.g. "[Homebrewing](http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/)" vs "[Homebrewing (Beer, Wine, etc.)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta&page=1)" Things like that.

Comment: How you refer to the sites among yourselves, as Stack Exchange employees?