# What do we call the individual Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion

As the title suggests, what, exactly, do we call the individual Stack Exchange sites? I've spent a while thinking about it and can't come up with an answer. Stacklets? Stacks? Exchangelets? Subexchanges? Is there an official name we use? It's odd that I've never seen the sites spoken of in this way, but I'm sure it's come up at least once in conversation.

**Note**: This is not a duplicate of this question: [What are the "proper" names for Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152405/what-are-the-proper-names-for-stack-exchange-sites) which is clearly very different.

Comment: as for me, I tend to call them _little stackies_ (on a more serious note, I recall them referred to as _Trilogy_ and _smaller sites_)

Comment: Stacklets when I'm not being serious, Stack Exchange sites when I am.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms)

Comment: @gnat I've poured over it twice and don't see what you're getting at. If you could point out where exactly the dictionary contains this term, I'd be grateful.

Comment: @ZachSmith look for "Stack Exchange network" and "Q&A sites"

Comment: @gnat I still don't see how that satisfies the question being asked here. None of the items in the glossary are at all satisfactory answers to the question.

Comment: @gnat Those are terms contained within various descriptions, not individual glossary items. I think that's a bit of a stretch as a duplicate.

Comment: Also, `Trilogy's ` supposed to refer to the three original sites (Stack Overflow, Superuser, and Server Fault). It's used to refer to all sites as a whole, but it isn't correct in that context.

Comment: Hmm yeah, I've seen people call them "stacks" and that really irritates me. They are "sites" for short, or "Stack Exchange sites" if you wish to be descriptive. Just like all other web sites.

Answer (score 7):

Stack Exchange sites.

<del>Or, since the About page for each site starts of with "**{site name} Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for..." they could be called "a Stack Exchange".</del>

Comment: From the [trademark guidance](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance): `A Stack Exchange site is a Q&A website built on the technology of Stack Exchange Inc. The phrase "Stack Exchange" is generally used as an adjective, not a noun. One would say "Propose a Stack Exchange site on Area 51" (correct), not "Propose a Stack Exchange on Area 51" (wrong).`

Comment: That darn trademark guidance. Might want to have a look at those `{site}.stackexchange.com/about` pages, then.

Comment: _One would say "Propose a Stack Exchange site on Area 51" (correct), not "Propose a Stack Exchange on Area 51" (wrong)._ Don't tell me what to do!

Comment: There's nothing with the grammar on the About page. It doesn't say "A Stack Exchange is a..." it says "Philosophy Stack Exchange is a..." Big difference—the latter is the actual name of the site, which is a discrete unit and can therefore be used with an article.