# Are there Common Conventions or Etiquette for Referencing Stack Exchange, and Users?

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette, grammar, citation

## Question

> 1. When ***writing about*** Stack Exchange, or ***citing from*** Stack Exchange, in research papers, citations, bibliographies, etc.: *Is there a Common Convention or Etiquette suggested when referring to Stack Exchange questions and users?*
> 2. Is there an official Stack Exchange guide, (a URL), regarding "Common Conventions", or "Etiquette" that may help clarify this, and other similar questions?

**Note:**

#1 is explicitly answered below.  However, in view of the comments, and questions, the "implicit" answer to #2 seems to be "No".

**Why:**

This would be very helpful -- given the wiki, and the fact that Stack is being cited formally, ([Citing Stack Overflow discussions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49760/citing-stack-overflow-discussions)).

**Note:**

Another `stack user` also noted the importance of generalizations - affirming that "Stack Etiquette", ([Stack Link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175009/how-can-i-reference-another-user-in-an-answer)) -- but they did not include a citation to a general etiquette "Thread".

**Related:**

1. Other Stack sites, ([Stack Link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152405/what-are-the-proper-names-for-stack-exchange-sites))? (Stacks? Exchanges?)
2. Other Questions? (Threads?)

OP's? Commenters? Questioners? Exchangers? Stackers? Editors?

## Wikipedia Example

Wikipedia refers to its users, and users refer to each other as [Wikipedians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wikipedians).

Although in practice, "Editors" seems to take precedence.

Comment: Uuuh. Are you serious? You feel the need to formalize this?

Comment: I agree that there should not be some "enforceable standard" -- However, in the artistic sense, it is a stylization opportunity for people who like to help edit and improve questions and answers -- especially when this information is published/sited elsewhere.

Comment: @elikakohen there's no right or wrong thing when addressing users. Do what you feel like doing. What we would probably recommend is `Stack Exchange users` or simply `users`, because that is, after all, what they are. This is very much opinion-based IMO.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ thanks.  That is about as official as it gets. :)  Would you mind posting this as "The Answer", so I can accept?

Comment: I really think that it was an error downvoting, kidding the user, and that was very useless to close the question. Is well written, clear, and he asked for a netiquette rule, not asked to _create_ a rule, but just _if is there a rule_. I hope one day downvoting and censoring like this will be avoided

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no right or wrong thing when addressing users really.

Do what you feel like doing. What *I* would recommend is 'Stack Exchange users' or simply 'users', because that is, after all, what they are.

Answer (score 8):

I'm going to address two of these that kinda bug me:

> Other Stack sites, (Stack Link)? (Stacks? Exchanges?)

Stack Exchange sites. Just 'Site' for short, if you like. **Not** 'Stacks', not 'Exchanges', and definitely not 'forums'

> Other Questions? (Threads?)

Questions. 'Threads' are a forum thing, and tend to imply 'discussion'. We have *comment* threads, but questions are not threads.

---

We don't need to formalize our terms for users. They're... users. Or people. Use natural language when referring to other people on the site.

Comment: Just referring to them as "SE sites" also suffices. Though I've seen many refer to Q/A as "Q/A threads".

Comment: Q&A yes, threads no - SE is not a discussion forum

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. **1. Thanks.**  I have seen "SE user, site, etc". However, sometimes the conventions used, (OP, SE), are ambiguous when they occur in citations, publications, print, etc. **2. And to: `@Undo`:**  I agree, "Natural Language" should be the way -- but "OP", "SE", etc, don't fulfill this; **3. However:** What I think you are stating, is: "To represent the culture of the Stack Communities: Just expand to natural language -- without specific formality";

Answer (score 4):

My personal preference is to use "community members" or "the community" in place of the word "users" (e.g. "What does the community think about this proposed feature?"). I personally don't like the word "users", because to me it implies that people who participate in Stack Exchange are just customers using a software product. To me, participating in Stack Exchange means being part of a community, not using a piece of software.

But it really is just a personal preference. You should use whatever word or phrase you think works best, so long as it isn't silly and makes sense. There is no need to create a new word to describe people who use Stack Exchange.