# Mobile theme 'X Answers' header doesn't take into account deleted answers

Tags: feature-request, bug, mobile-web, deleted-answers

At 10k, you can start seeing deleted posts. The main web version takes this into account and displays the total number of answers (deleted and non-deleted):

[image]

However, for the mobile theme, it doesn't (same question in screenshot):

[image]

It's not that you can't see deleted posts in the mobile theme, because you can (erased all information, just showing screenshot to show the red deleted background):

[image]

---

So can it be made more consistent with the web version, and the correct number shown please?

BTW I was using [this question as my example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269389/260841) -- you can test the mobile theme yourself by clicking the 'mobile' link in the footer.